# How can I detect pasted text on iPhone with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, copy-paste, paste

I'm working on a cross-platform website where the UI will change based on user input. One such change is that each time a certain input is filled, either by typing or copy-pasting, it will reveal a hidden input. The problem? Getting it to work on iPhone.

Currently I **am** successfully detecting copy-pastes on desktops (primarily using onKeyUp). And much to my dismay I discovered that onPaste doesn't get the job done. So that's why I'm here. Is there any kind of jQuery magic that can save this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect paste with. it works on phones too

```
$('input').on('paste', function(){
// do something
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go.

```
function noCTRL(e)
{
  var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode:e.which;
  var ctrl = (document.all) ? event.ctrlKey:e.modifiers & Event.CONTROL_MASK;
  var msg = "Sorry, this functionality is disabled.";
  if (document.all)
  {
    if (ctrl && code==86) //CTRL+V
    {
      alert(msg);
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
    else if (ctrl && code==67) //CTRL+C (Copy)
    {
      alert(msg);
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (ctrl==2) //CTRL key
    {
      alert(msg);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
Email :<input name="email" type="text" value=""/><br/>
Password :<input name="password" type="password" value=""/><br/>
Confirm Email :<input name="email" type="text" value="" onkeydown="return noCTRL(event)"/>    
Confirm Password :<input name="password" type="password" value="" onkeydown="return noCTRL(event)"/>
```